# Origin of "to be into [someone] for [a sum of money]"

Tags: etymology, slang

*"He's into me for fifty quid"* means *"He owes me fifty pounds"*. It's common enough in the UK, but I'm fairly sure I've heard it in American movies too (*bucks* or *grand* there, not *quid*, obviously), so I don't think it's particularly a UK expression.

But since I just had reason to say it, I got to wondering "Why 'into'?", and realised it's a bit odd. Is it just short for *"in debt to"*? When I say it, I feel like *"into"* is one word, and a quick Google shows that's how people write it, but if you just miss out the word *"debt"* you'd still have two words left.

Anyone know the origin/first use?

Comment: FWIW I had to read the question to know the meaning. British, but obviously not moving in the appropriate circles to hear this phrase.

Comment: @slim: It has a London/Cockney "feel" to me, but in my "mind's ear" I imagine the amount being [so many "grand"], and "grand" feels American, so I really don't even know where it got started, let alone when or why.

Comment: I can personally attest to use of "into" or "in to" in Texas with the identical meaning, so this is not purely a Britishism.

Comment: "In to" means "in debt to" and may simply be a shortening of the latter. But like many slang terms it may be impossible to identify the origin, just early uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Partridge

Partridge's [*A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=tvRp1whVFUsC&pg=PA599&dq=%22he%27s%20into%20me%20for%20*%20dollars%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ckQZT66CCqLm4QTtn5HFDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22he%27s%20into%20me%20for%22&f=false) (2002) says:

[image: screenshot]

> **into** (a person) **for** (a sum of money), **be**. To owe a person so-much, to have let him down for a stated amount: Can, coll.: late C. 19-20. John Bearnes, *Gateway*, 1932, He's into me for ninety dollars, and I can't get a cent out of him.'

Where *Can coll.* is Canadian colloquial. The [2007](http://books.google.fi/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PR9&dq=%2B%22into%22+slang+partridge&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GGAZT-SCBPOk4AS6pqjCDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22in%20debt%20to%22&f=false) edition more simply says:

> **into** *preposition* **1** in debt to, *US, 1893*

---

### *"... into me for ..."*

Diving into Google Books, here's a possible [1902](http://books.google.fi/books?id=DYkXAQAAMAAJ&q=%22into%20me%20for%20*%20dollars%22&dq=%22into%20me%20for%20*%20dollars%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_0UZT823Mu7c4QSY4pXODQ&redir_esc=y) from the American *Ainslee's Magazine*, Volume 10, Issues 1-6:

[image]

> "Old man," confided Bill, after explaining the situation, "I need just a dollar and ten cents. Let me have it, like a good fellow." "But, Bill," replied Reece, hesitatingly, "**you're into me for fifty dollars** already."

And a [definite](http://www.archive.org/details/pitcherinparadi00binsgoog) [1903](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%27s%20into%20me%20for%20*%20dollars%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:1940,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22into%20me%20for%20*%20quid%22&psj=1&oq=%22into%20me%20for%20*%20quid%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4589l4921l1l5047l4l2l0l0l0l1l115l199l1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=ba5ddbfe61d3af9b&biw=1920&bih=1062) from Arthur Morris Binstead's *Pitcher in Paradise: Some Random Reminiscences, Sporting and Otherwise*, published in London:

> Two unplaced's an' one second, an' damme, **she was into me for thirty-eight quid !** Stupid ? Aye, laad, even the bloomin' clerk rounded on me !

Here's a possible [1890](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22into%20me%20for%22&hl=en&biw=1920&bih=1062&sa=X&ei=Nm8ZT5uwDciH4gS-tcTDDQ&ved=0CBkQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:,cd_max:1904&tbm=bks#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_max:1904&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22into%20me%20for%20all%20I%27m%20worth%22&psj=1&oq=%22into%20me%20for%20all%20I%27m%20worth%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=891216l894775l2l895380l14l12l2l0l0l2l205l1537l2.6.2l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=ba5ddbfe61d3af9b&biw=1920&bih=1062) in *Puck* magazine which may be using a with a pun on the phrase:

> "**You 've got into me for all I 'm worth**," remarked the Stocking to the Jumping-Jack. "All the same, I'm in a hole," replied the Jumping-Jack. And when Santa Claus heard them talking in that way, he broke the Jumping-Jack and took the ...

### *Walked* and *dribbled*

Here's an interesting one from a possibly [1903](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=hW4ZT_fGGa_74QSE-8nbDQ&id=aa8RAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22into%20me%20for%20*%20thousand%22&q=%22into%20me%20for%22) *Pearson's Magazine*:

[image]

> He has dribbled into me for a thousand if he's had a cent, and now he must pay back by taking a chance.

*Dribbling* can also be found in the possibly [1917](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=hW4ZT_fGGa_74QSE-8nbDQ&id=CKIYAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22into%20me%20for%20*%20thousand%22&q=%22into%20me%20for%20%22#search_anchor) *Norsk-Engelsk Ordbog*:

[image]

> ***summer*** little sums  ; *cont* driblets, petty sums. *Cold has dribbled into me for a thousand ;*

And finally, [these](http://books.google.fi/books?id=TucXAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA692&dq=%22into%20me%20for%20*%20hundred%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ymYZT4jkBvKM4gT_2LySDQ&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=%22into%20me%20for%22&f=false) [two](http://books.google.fi/books?id=hdUNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA115&dq=%22into%20me%20for%20*%20thousand%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XmYZT-LiAa774QS1xoHdDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22walked%20into%20me%20for%22&f=false) have *walked into me for a [sum]*, which could be part of the same phrase.

Comment: Interesting Partridge says *to have let him down*. I was going to say in the question I don't usually hear it in respect of "routinely-arranged" borrowing (from a bank, say). Usually it's some context where you had to bail someone out unexpectedly, or they did something causing you a financial loss that they've acknowledged, but they're not in a position to make recompense right now. Does that *"Can. coll"* mean "Canadian"?

Comment: I can't see the abbreviations in that 2002 book, but another [1973 Partridge](http://books.google.fi/books?id=0voNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA368&dq=%2B%22into%22+slang+debt+money&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5mIZT5DKCO-M4gSd3MTpDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22into%20a%20person%22&f=false) has the same definition but with *Canadian coll.*. A [2007 Partridge](http://books.google.fi/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PR9&dq=%2B%22into%22+slang+partridge&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GGAZT-SCBPOk4AS6pqjCDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22in%20debt%20to%22&f=false) says: **into** *preposition* **1** in debt to, *US, 1893*

Comment: Those two at the end are much older than the rest, so I'm more than prepared to believe they're at least part of why the operative word today is **into*. Does it for me, ty!

Answer (score 2):

‘Chambers Slang Dictionary’ has two entries for *into*. The first gives ‘owing money to’, but also ‘having taken payment for a job’. It dates it to the late nineteenth century with a US origin.

It can, of course, also have the more or less opposite meaning when we speak of someone *coming into* some money.